# Debian Jessie Kernel won't install, could be a grub2 issue?

Tags: kernel, debian-jessie, grub2

I have an issue with one of my xen VMs that I would like resolved
doing `apt-get install -f` shows following. Can anyone help me make sense of this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 33, in <module>
    from ALChacks import *
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALChacks.py", line 25, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from encodings import aliases
ImportError: cannot import name aliases
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.43-2+deb8u2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/grub-probe)
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1)
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: symbol dm_log, version Base not defined in file libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 with link time reference
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have messed up your python environment, it can't import what it needs. Other people online have this problem on Ubuntu and seem to be able to fix it by reinstalling python.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/360004/ubuntu-12-04-update-manager-and-software-center-is-not-working/360104

Comment: Nah that is not the problem .. reinstalling won't do anything ...